# How to calculate if a co-location intercept is possible in a ballistic counter-battery scenario

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v, rendezvous, ballistics

Let us presume that we have a scenario with ballistic objects.  As an example, one object $m_1$ is launched at time $t_0$ from Earth Location $a$ towards Earth Location $b$, both of which are in the same hemisphere, positioned so that a minimum time trajectory must go over one polar region, and are between 60° and 120° apart. Then at some time $t_1$ between the first launch and its impact at $t_2$, a ballistic object $m_2$ is launched from $b$ toward the first object's launch site $a$, to impact at $t_3$.

Both ballistic objects are on flight paths with approximately the same eccentricity, chosen to minimise flight time as far as practical.

While the objects will both pass roughly over the pole, the trajectories are not superimposed since the Earth is rotating, and at closest approach the objects are a considerable distance apart.

However, while launched from $a$ in such a manner that it should not have to use it to reach $b$, $m_1$ has an on-board capability to generate delta-V, and if it has *sufficient* delta-V, it has the capability of targeting and manoeuvring to generate a collision with $m_2$.

**Question:** How can I calculate the minimum amount of delta-V required to alter the trajectory of $m_1$ starting at $t_1$ so that it will impact $m_2$ at some time between $m_2$'s launch at $t_1$ and $m_1$'s impact at $m_2$'s launch site $b$ at $t_2$ or $m_2$'s impact at $m_1$'s launch site $a$ at $t_3$?

$m_2$ should be considered to have no way of having its trajectory altered once launched.

---

My thinking so far:

Obviously, if $t_1$=$t_2$, then $m_1$'s delta-V required will be minimal.  I am more concerned with solutions in the range $t_1 = 0$ to $t_1 = t_0 +(t_2-t_0)/2$, i.e. $m_2$'s launch at $t_1$ occurring with $m_1$ half-way along its trajectory.

Since this is a missile counter-battery question, this is not a zero-velocity rendezvous, but should be an impact that takes place at as high a closing velocity as practical, effectively meaning that no deceleration or course-matching by $m_1$ to meet $m_2$ is necessary.

I have access to AGI's free STK 11.2 software package, but I have none of the paid add-ons that would make this question unnecessary, since I am not only short of funds, but I am also not American, and hence prohibited from receiving the most relevant of AGI's packages even as a trial due to US export restrictions, and I have also exhausted the use of trial licenses for the paid packages that I am able to receive.

On the other hand, I can write my own code, either stand-alone or interop with STK, but I lack knowledge of the math involved.

Additionally, how can I calculate the impact velocity and the maximum extent of the debris field in the event of a successful intercept?

Comment: Actually, this question could probably be asked in six or eight *carefully written* sentences. *Site 1 launches ballistic missile to hit Site 2, Site 2 detects it early in flight and launches ballistic missile to hit Site 1. Because of the Earth's rotation and different launch times, they will not intercept each other ballistically, but Site 1's missile has thrust capability! Once SIte 1's missile sees the other missile in flight, it will divert to intercept it. How can I calculate the necessary $\Delta v$ for this maneuver?* or something similar.

Comment: Minimizing eccentricity doesn't necessarily minimize velocity. See http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2014/06/travel-on-airless-worlds.html

Comment: @uhoh, this scenario is specifically New York City to central China, and is part of a future chapter of my The Juggernaut series in Worldbuilding SE's Universe Factory on Medium https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-26073bba4e37 where alien automaton Jormungandr is sitting in NYC, firing self-guided railgun rounds at China's ICBMs, and the Chinese, warned by the US after they lose their *own* land-based ICBMs, decide to use them rather than lose them.  Still, I expect that the math would be the same regardless of the exact source of M1 and M2, and only the numbers would change.

Comment: @uhoh, it doesn't have to be that exact scenario,  I can plug in my own numbers, I just don't know the math to use.  If you and others would prefer a more generic question, then I'm happy to oblige, and I'll take specific locations out of the question entirely.   I'd be quite happy with a generic answer with no specific numbers, since I can put my numbers in for myself.

Comment: @uhoh, on further reflection, I've made the actual question completely generic, and have removed any references to specific locations.  The locations I'm interested in can stay in the comments.

Comment: @MontyWild OK that's fine I guess. You may want to at least mention they are both in the same hemisphere, and will be aiming over the same pole. Using (-30, 45) and (+150, 45) makes that obvious, but with $a$ and $b$ you should say it explicitly. Looks good though. I'm going to clean up most of the comments in a few minutes.

Comment: @uhoh, I've put in a few relevant constraints, and added a sub-question about impact velocity and debris.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this--in a counterbattery scenario the intercepting missile will be fired on the correct trajectory in the first place.  If the tracking and rocket are perfect the intercept delta-V is zero.  In practice neither input is perfect and thus you'll need a bit.  The only substantial need for delta-V is to get the interceptor out there in the first place.

Comment: If you're defending a point source (a base, a ship etc.) then you only need enough delta-V to get your interceptor above the detonation altitude of the inbound.  If you're doing area defense you also need enough to get the interceptor over to the inbound trajectory in time.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, I just want to know how to calculate how much delta-V is required to make the specified intercept. In practise, the intercepting missile is a multirole platform. Once I know how much delta-V, I'll decide if it is realistic that the missile carry that much.

Comment: Which is a different question than you asked before.  You're now asking for the delta-v from launch, the original asked for the delta-v of an intercept while already in flight.  Break the problem down: Figure out when and where the inbound will detonate.  Now figure what it will take to get an interceptor to that point, add a bit as you need to intercept before that point.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, the question hasn't changed.  M1 is launched,  then M2, and then we see how much delta-V it will take for M1 to change course to intercept M2.  I was never asking for the delta-V from launch, I already know that.